# Embedding build number into .js file

Tags: javascript, build, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online) for our CI (Continuous Integration). After each successful build, I would like to embed the *build number* into a `.js` file (or `.html` file) to display on our about page. Something like:

```
let v = $(BUILD_NUMBER);
```

where of course `$(BUILD_NUMBER)` would be replaced with the actual build number, evaluating to a `number` at runtime. I've been digging the build documentation for a while now, but I only found how to pull this off with an ASP.NET build, which is not what I need.

**So how do I go about injecting the build number into a Javascript file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Command Line task recognizes [Build Variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables), which allows us to run e.g. a powershell command to do a replace in a file. So, for example, if we have:

**version.js**

```
let v = BUILD_NUMBER;
```

then the following command can be run to inject the build number:

```
powershell -Command "(gc version.js) -replace 'BUILD_NUMBER', '$(Build.BuildId)' | Out-File version.js"
```

which, given a build ID of e.g. `123`, will yield:

**version.js**

```
let v = 123;
```